# foreach in php getting an error

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am getting the error in a following code:

```
foreach ($result2 as $result2) {


$result2[$i]=  explode(",", $result2[$j]);
}
```

The error is

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\eplus\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_controller_product_product.php
on line 417Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in
```

What can I do?

Comment: Need to check your total code

Answer (score 5):

You have given both the variables as `$result2` in the `foreach()`

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($result2 as $result) {
    $result2[$i]=  explode(",", $result[$j]);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but error remains the same.

Comment: Can you check $result2 is an array or string.?The error shows that $result2 is a string.For using in the foreach() it must be an array

Comment: It is an array after I used explode function.

Answer (score 1):

You may want ...

```
foreach ($result2 as $k=>$result) {
    $result2[$k] = explode(',', $result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre immediately overwriting $result2 with the first value of it. If this value is not an array, you can't loop over it again. just make something like $result2 as $res2

Comment: Sorry error still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump($result2)` and see whether the variable actually is an array.

Comment: array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "5040"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "5040"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "5040"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "5040"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}